# Submit FORM with js and triger Event 'submit'

Tags: javascript, ajax

**Hi everyone**
So there is my code :

HTML :

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="image">
            <input onchange="test();" type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" name="file" id="camera">
            <input id="go" type="submit" value="Stash the file!" style="display: none;" />
        </form>
        <div id="output"></div>
    </body>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
</html>
```

JS :

```
var form = document.forms.namedItem("image");
form.addEventListener('submit', function(ev) {

   var
       oOutput = document.getElementById("output"),
       oData = new FormData(document.forms.namedItem("image"));

   oData.append("CustomField", "This is some extra data");

   var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
   oReq.open("POST", "./upload.php", true);
   oReq.onload = function(oEvent) {
       if (oReq.status == 200) {
           oOutput.innerHTML = "Uploaded!";
       } else {
           oOutput.innerHTML = "Error " + oReq.status + " occurred uploading your file.<br \/>";
       }
   };

   oReq.send(oData);
   ev.preventDefault();
}, false);

function test() {
   document.getElementById("go").click()
}
```

My problem is it's totaly functional but litlle... dirty.

I try to submit the form with JS `document.forms.namedItem("image").submit();` but the EventListener dont catch it.

And i dont want to add JQuery to my project just for that (for those who have an answer who use JQuery).

The solution is certainly right before my eyes but i dont find an other way to do it.

Thanks all in advance.

Comment: [`namedItem()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/namedItem) is for `option` elements, not forms. Use `document.querySelector("form[name='image']").submit();`

Comment: Is it functional or not? As such I don't find it so dirty, we see much dirtier code here on a daily basis...

Comment: @ScottMarcus It could be used like that before but I think it's deprecated

Comment: @LaurentS. Huh? `namedItem()` is not deprecated. It's just not used as a general selector - - it's specific to `option` elements within a `select` as you can see if you look at the link I shared. `.querySelector()` is the modern standard for accessing single elements within the DOM.

Comment: I was refering to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) but I think I misread it...

Comment: @ScottMarcus `document.querySelector("form[name='image']").submit();` doesn't triger my event listener unfortunately.

@LaurentS. Like i said in my post yes it's functionial. But i use js to simulate a click on an hidden button it kinda feels like breaking into my own car when i'd much rather use the key. I'm looking for a "car key" solution fo my problems

Comment: It certainly does. Please see my answer below for a working example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can simplify like this :

```js
function pleaseUpload() {
   console.log('upload fonction ...');
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="image">
            <input onchange="pleaseUpload();" type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" name="file" id="camera">
        </form>
        <div id="output"></div>
    </body>
    <script src="./temp.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your confusing `form.submit()` with `submit` button `click`.

There is no need for a hidden submit button.

```js
var output = document.getElementById("output");
var form = document.querySelector("form[name='image']");
form.addEventListener('submit', function(ev) {
   ev.preventDefault();
   var oOutput = document.getElementById("output")
   var oData = new FormData(document.forms.namedItem("image"));

   oData.append("CustomField", "This is some extra data");

   var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
   oReq.open("POST", "./upload.php", true);
   oReq.onload = function(oEvent) {
       if (oReq.status == 200) {
           oOutput.innerHTML = "Uploaded!";
       } else {
           oOutput.innerHTML = "Error " + oReq.status + " occurred uploading your file.<br \/>";
       }
   };
   oReq.send(oData);

}, false);

function test() {
   form.submit();
   output.textContent = "form submitted!";
}
```

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="image">
  <input onchange="test();" type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" name="file" id="camera">
</form>
<div id="output"></div>
```